# Java web start fails to start - JRE 7 32 bit (running on 64 bit windows system)

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have removed all JDKs/JREs (using the uninstaller), removed the JavaSoft stuff from the registry, removed JAVA_HOME from the environment variables, removed any reference to Java in the "Path" environment variable.

Then I installed JDK 7u11 for 32 bit system.

When I try to use Java webstart (either via the browser or directly from the command line), I get the Java 7 splash screen briefly, and then a dialog that says "Unable to Launch the Application", clicking on the "Details" button yields this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.config.JREInfo.validateHomeJRE_int(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.JREInfo.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.ClientConfig.refreshProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.ClientConfig.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WebStartConfig.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.ClientConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WebStartConfig.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I am executing the right javaws.exe file (I'm trying this with the command line to be sure).

I googled this and found only one unhelpful link:

http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/  (look in the comments section, apparently someone else has the same problem, but not resolved).

Comment: Maybe you should raise a bug with Oracle.

Comment: It sounds like it hasn't installed properly. Can you try installing the 64-bit version?

Comment: when running "javaws -viewer" can you see in the java tab -> ... -> your jdk on the correct path and enabled? Another idea: did you restart after installation?

Comment: Have you set new JAVA_HOME after installing?

Comment: What does give you command `java -version` in console?

Comment: @PeterButkovic - "javaws -viewer" yields exactly the same result. I restarted the machine before I tried this.

Comment: @lechlukasz - I tried setting JAVA_HOME to the location of the JRE and no difference.

Comment: OK, you have some problem in installation then. can you run at least java ? or does it crash for you?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - works fine when I uninstall and install the 64-bit version. But I want only a 32-bit version on my machine. I think I will redownload and install the 32 bit version (I have reinstalled it a few times).

Comment: @FrancisUpton Out of curiosity, why would you want only the 32-bit version.  AFAIK you only need it if you have 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I'm running 32 bit eclipse installations both for development and my target. They don't run on 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 3):

solution is here

http://allenwu.logdown.com/posts/253492-not-open-the-java-control-panel

as is delete all under 
\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's still working in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

My steps:

- Uninstall all JRE and JDK program versions.
- Delete all directories:

  - Oracle/Java
  - Javasoft
  - Java
  - Sun/Java
- From ALL system directories:

  - Program files
  - Program files(x86)
  - `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\`
  - `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\LocalLow\`
- Reinstall Oracle JRE or JDK

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I re-downloaded the 32 bit Java from the Oracle site and installed it again and it worked.

When I uninstalled the 64-bit version and installed the 32-bit version, it did not properly associate the jnlp files with javaws.exe, so I had to do this manually using the Windows mechanism. Once that was done it works.

Thanks everyone for all your help!